# Catching Webhook from Zoome

Tags: google-apps-script, webhooks

I try to use Google App Script to catch an event notification from Zoom. The payload is JSON and below is my code.

```js
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('doGet request');
}

function doPost(e) {    
  try {
    var input = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
    input = JSON.parse(input);
    //var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(myData);
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("doPost received");
}
```

However, on the WebApp, I'm getting "The script completed but did not return anything"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

#### Modification points:

- When `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput` is returned, the message of `The script completed but did not return anything` is not returned.

  - I think that your Web Apps might be required to be redeployed as new version.
- When you want to use the Web Apps as the webhook, I think that `ContentService.createTextOutput` might be suitable rather than `HtmlService.createHtmlOutput`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function doGet(e) {
  return ContentService.createTextOutput('doGet request'); // Modified
}

function doPost(e) {    
  try {
    var input = JSON.stringify(e.postData.contents);
    input = JSON.parse(input);
    //var myData = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    //return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(myData);
  }
  catch (e) {
    throw new Error(e);
  }
  return ContentService.createTextOutput("doPost received"); // Modified
}
```

#### Note:

- **After you modified your script like above, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Class ContentService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for the advice. It worked. However, now my webhook is getting status 302, i'm not sure why. Do you have any advice?

Comment: I have posted a new question. Thank you so much for your help!